# "Cannot GET" error when doing href to file in parent folder

Tags: html

I am trying to link to another html file which is located in a different folder. The files are in the following folders:

Wevdev/DigitalMedia/image1.html

and the other is in:

Webdev/Labs/Directory.html

Hyperlinks are working when linking between files in the same folder but getting an error when trying to link to a file in a different folder.

```
<img src="arrow-3D-green-left.jpg">
<a href="http://wikipedia.com"><img src="rome1.jpg"></a>
<img src="arrow-3D-green-right.jpg"><br>

<h1>Image 1</h1>

<a href="=../Labs/Directory.html">Link to directory</a>
```

The page opens in chrome with the following error message:

Cannot GET /Labs/Directory.html

Comment: can you open ```/Labs/Directory.html``` manually in browser? (Not using link)

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but you mention `directory.html` in one part, and `Directory.html` in another part. Depending the server host, this could be case-sensitive.

Comment: @NormanBreau ```/Labs/Directory.html``` in ```<a>``` tag's address in code is the same as error ```Cannot GET /Labs/Directory.html```

Comment: @Scott Yes the filename is Directory.html and I can open it manually in the browser without the link.

Comment: Make another html page and directories and test with them. if it works properly on the same server. check ```/Labs/Directory.html``` permissions.

Comment: @Scott I figured it out. It was because I didn't have the parent directory open in brackets so it wasn't able to reach the parent directory.

Comment: @scottwsmyth Awesome! Please post your solution as an answer just in case someone else have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using extra `=` after `href="` .I think just a type mistake:

```
<a href="../Labs/Directory.html">Link to directory</a>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error but thanks for the heads up on the typo.

Comment: I tested and working fine. Recreate directories and files or check folders or files permissions as  said@Scott

Answer (score 0):

This is where the problem is. You must move two directories back:

```
<a href="../../Labs/Directory.html">Link to directory</a>
```

Moving back once `../` doesn't take you to the parrent directory.

Copy and paste this and try.